# Making part of text bold in custom Textblock breaks binding

Tags: wpf

I am trying to make a part text as "bold" but after doing this binding breaks and correct text values are not getting reflected back in TextBlock

TextBlock i used is custom and following is the code block for making text bold

XAML Code

```
 <StackPanel Margin="10" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListNames}" SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItem}">
        </ComboBox>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
        <controls:TrimmedToolTipTextBlock Name="txbInfoText" TextWrapping="Wrap" Visibility="Visible"
                                          controls:TextBlockFormatter.FormattedText="{Binding Text, ElementName=txbInfoText}"
               Margin="10,0,0,0" 
               FontSize="13" TextAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock.Text>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource StringFormatConverter}">
                    <localization:Localize Key="Message"/>
                    <Binding Path="Name" IsAsync="True" />
                    <Binding Path="Address"/>
                    <Binding Path="City"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBlock.Text>
        </controls:TrimmedToolTipTextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
```

In this code block I have a combobox and custom TrimmedToolTipTextBlock, on changing selected item in combo-box , value in textblock should change accordingly.Message value is coming from Resource file which accepts Name,Address and City as parameter and part of message text is inside  tags.

CS code block

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty FormattedTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("FormattedText", typeof(string), typeof(TextBlockFormatter),
        new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty, (sender, e) =>
        {
            string text = e.NewValue as string;

            if (!text.Contains("<b>"))
                return;

            var textBlock = sender as TextBlock;
            if (textBlock != null)
            {
                textBlock.Inlines.Clear();
                var tags = text.Split(new string[] { "<b>", "</b>" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                for (int i = 0; i < tags.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tags[i]))
                        textBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run { Text = tags[i], FontWeight = i % 2 == 1 ? FontWeights.Bold : FontWeights.Normal });

                }
            }
        }));
```

In this code block i am identifying part of text which are inside  tags and changing it's font weight to bold.

Comment: This is confusing. You have a MultiBinding on the Text property of a derived TextBlock, then you bind an attached property to the Text property, just to subsequently change that same Text property in the attached property's PropertyChangedCallback. That can't work. Why don't you directly assign the MultiBinding to the attached property?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but I guess it should work if you assign the MultiBinding directly to the attached property:

```
<controls:TrimmedToolTipTextBlock ...>
    <controls:TextBlockFormatter.FormattedText>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource StringFormatConverter}">
            <localization:Localize Key="Message"/>
            <Binding Path="Name" IsAsync="True" />
            <Binding Path="Address"/>
            <Binding Path="City"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </controls:TextBlockFormatter.FormattedText>
</controls:TrimmedToolTipTextBlock>
```